# change url and update page content without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where everything is called by php function.
Which function is called and what is displayed on the page depends on the url of the page. It gets data from url and makes changes.
Function Example:

```
switch($DO){
    case 'edit':
        editorProfile('1');
        break;

    case 'Add':
         addpeople('1');
        break;

    case 'about':
          show_about('1');
        break;

         case 'jobs':
        show_jobs('3',$details['cid']);
        break;

    case 'photo':
         show_photo('3',$details['cid']);
        break;

       ?>
```

GET the variable

```
   $DO=$_GET['dothis'];
```

html

```
  link 1 <a href="mypage.php?dothis=edit">edit</a>
   link 1 <a href="mypage.php?dothis=add">add</a>
    link 1 <a href="mypage.php?dothis=about">about</a>
     link 1 <a href="mypage.php?dothis=photo">photo</a>
```

Currently, it is working perfectly but the page gets reloaded.
 I want something which changes the url, updates the content but does not reload the whole pag.

I know this can be done by:

```
 window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

But I have no idea how to implement this and what changes have to be done in case of old browsers(in case of old browsers,if this is not supported the page just gets reloaded).

Comment: Ajax is the best for dynamic changes without reloading!

Comment: I am not sure if you can change the `url` *(I assume you mean in the address bar...)*.

Answer (score -1):

Check out wiselinks I use it and think it is amazing.  https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks.  It is a jquery ajax library that can handle just about anything that you can throw at it.  I use it for most of my webpages because you can create super fast browsing and seo friendly ajax sites.  I think it should be good for what you need it for as well.  It will change the url in the browser and the title as well without page reloads.

Answer (score -1):

What you try to achieve cannot be done with PHP. It will reload every time.

You have to use Ajax to make the request asynchronously and avoid reloading.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Concerning the URL, I'm not sure if you can change it without reloading, even in Ajax.

Comment: window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url"); see this

Comment: I was not sure, now I'm sure it is possible :) Thx for the info.